# what's the reason for showing this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') at newIndex.html:45:16

Tags: javascript, html

**problem**
I am trying to learn JavaScript eventLinster on multiple HTML elements. My code is working, but an unexpected error is being appeared.

**The error is** "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') at newIndex.html:45:16"

**myCode:**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Change Style</title>
    <style>
      button {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      button:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border: 3px solid black;
        transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>You didn't click any button.</h1>

    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>


    <script>
      var heading = document.querySelector("h1");
      const btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");

      var len = btn.length;

      for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", func);
        function func() {
          var txt = this.innerHTML;
          heading.innerHTML = txt + " is clicked.";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to access out of bounds array element. You loop condition is i <= len, but last element in your array is len - 1 (arrays are 0 indexed).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Change Style</title>
    <style>
      button {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      button:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border: 3px solid black;
        transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>You didn't click any button.</h1>

    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>


    <script>
        var heading = document.querySelector("h1");
        const btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");

        var len = btn.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          btn[i].addEventListener("click", func);
          function func() {
            var txt = this.innerHTML;
            heading.innerHTML = txt + " is clicked.";
          }
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer does not describe the reason why the code in the question was wrong and/or how to fix it.